# How to use push notification got from parse in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications

How to get the values return from a push notification and display them inside a `TextView`. I have tried this on my class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                    String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String mesg = jsonObject.getString("message");



                    Intent intent2open = new Intent(context, DealWithNotice.class);
                    intent2open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    String name = "KEY";
                    String value = title;
                    intent2open.putExtra(name, value);
                    Log.d("Value", value);
                    context.startActivity(intent2open);


                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I will be happy to get this off my sleeve

Comment: What specifically is the error or problem that you're having?

Comment: my jsonObject wasn't returning any value. So when i call the intent it returns null.